# Total Social Count With AddThis HTML Plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css, social-networking, addthis

We use AddThis on our Blog to allow please to share out posts. We would like to count the amount of people that share the content but AddThis shows how many people have shared it for each network and we would prefer it to be all in one small section.

This is how the code is basically right now.

```
<div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox" style="text-align:center;display:block;">
    <a class=“at-share-btn at-svc-facebook”>… </a>
         <span class="at_flat_counter">50</span>
    <a class=“at-share-btn at-svc-twitter”>… </a>
         <span class="at_flat_counter">23</span>
    <a class=“at-share-btn at-svc-tumblr”>… </a>
         <span class="at_flat_counter">1</span>
    <a class=“at-share-btn at-svc-google_plus”>… </a>
         <span class="at_flat_counter">2</span>
    <a class=“at-share-btn at-svc-linkedin”>… </a>
         <span class="at_flat_counter">1</span>
</div>
```

What we would like to do is add all of the numbers between the spans and then add them together so we can display them in one field that is the total count. The issue is that I don't know if that is even possible.

Once the count is completed we will user `display: none;` to hide the `<span class="at_flat_counter">1</span>` supplied by AddThis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.at-svc-compact, .at_flat_counter { display:none !important; }
.at_flat_counter:last-child { display:inline-block !important; }
```

First line hides the AddThis icon that how the total count next to it as well as all of the counter elements.

The second line shows the AddThis total count element - therefore appearing to the user without AddThis branding and also showing the total amount of shares for the page on multiple platforms